# How to grant permissions (ACL) when working with nested groups?

Tags: permissions, acl, groups

I pushed a topic here that has not yet been solved in the forum and that affects our organizations:

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=29381

Managing ACLs is really heavy and is very inefficient to have to grant and maintain permissions one to one to a set of groups that in fact hang from a parent group.

Has anyone encountered the same trouble?

Comment: Could you phrase this in the form of a single, clear question?

Comment: I've just found that this is still (4.7.24) the case: If you assign an ACL Role access to contacts in a parent group it will not apply to contacts in the child group. Would be a very helpful feature!

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem - and solved it by implementing a multi-site configuration and installing the [Multisite Permissioning extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/multisite-permissioning).

This may not be appropriate for your setting, it may create more trouble than it solves, but in our case it was very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Jon, but for us it creates more trouble than it solves, especially because it would add much complexity to the already heavy definition of ACLs.
Anyway I guess if it has not been able to respond to an issue like this is partly due to the complexity involved in developing a solution for this.